# How to force facebook share button to share the url in a different format?

Tags: php, facebook

I use the following share button to my page. Unfortunately my urls that are shared through my page have Greek letters in it "as" below:

```
http://www.domain.com/gb/news/12/13311/the-name-of-article-written-in-greek.htm
```

and I guess this causes a problem where the facebook does not show any image or content of the page. It only shows the url.

I found out that if I manually cut the above url to

```
http://www.domain.com/gb/news/12/13311/
```

the share works properly and the current page is shown. Everything is great.

*So my question is* how should I force the facebook share button to share the page after the modification? I know that by using `var_dump($url['dirname']);` I get the format I want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [FB docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/), you can specify any URL you wish by populating the `SHARE_URL` a tag attribute:

```
<a name="fb_share" type="button" share_url="<?php echo $url['dirname'] ?>"></a>
```

By the way, what you are referring to is a [canonical](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) url, trimming this:

```
http://www.domain.com/gb/news/12/13311/the-name-of-article-written-in-greek.htm
```

To this:

```
http://www.domain.com/gb/news/12/13311/
```

The beauty of canonical urls is that they will not change, even though you decide to change keywords in the pretty url version. Useful for sitemaps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FaceBook OG (open graph) tags to tell facebook what the "real" url is of the page. If you're serious about facebook sharing, you should be using those already. Put these in your

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Titeel Goes Here"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="URL goes here"/>
```

Verify what Facebook sees here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug. You can also add a thumbnail image, and admin (so you can better see the likes and who shared).